# Varnish: rewrite/reguide requests after after API call possible?

Tags: varnish

How can I make Varnish work like a switch?

I need to consult an authentication service with a request of the original client request. That authentication service checks upon original request if access is permitted and replies simply with a status code and probably some more information in the header. Upon that status code and header information from that auth service, I would like varnish to serve content from different backends. Depending on the status code the backend can vary and I would like to add some additional header before Varnish fetches the content.

Finally varnish should cache and reply to client.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's doable using some VCL and VMODs. For example, you could use the [cURL VMOD](https://github.com/varnish/libvmod-curl) during `vcl_recv` in order to trigger the HTTP request against the authentication service, check response, and then use that info for backend selection and other caching decisions (that would be just simple VCL). A much better alternative would be the [http VMOD](https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/http/), but that one is only available in Varnish Enterprise. In fact, a similar example to what you want to achieve is available in the linked documentation; see 'HTTP Request' section.

In any case, it would be a good idea to minimise interactions with the authentication service using some high performance caching mechanism. For example, you could use the [redis VMOD](https://github.com/carlosabalde/libvmod-redis) for that (or even Varnish itself!).

Comment: Nice one, I will try one day!